# I want default argument promotion's example

Tags: c

At C standard 6.5.2.2. paragraph 6

> If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that does not include a prototype, the
>   integer promotions are performed on each argument, and arguments that have type float are
>   promoted to double. These are called the default argument promotions.

"the expression that denotes the called function has a type that does not include a prototype" What can this be described as code?

```
char a = 1;
printf("%d", a); /*"the expression that denotes the called function" is printf, and `a`
doesn't have prototype(char). but a can't be replaced as `char a` originally.  ...? */
```

This is my thought that can be applicable to above standard. Is this right?

Comment: C99 doesn't allow implicitly defined functions any more (removing a defect of the language...). If you happen to compile for older standards, I only can recommend `-Werror=implicit` command line option (GCC! – most other compilers have similar options, though). Be aware that these promotions then still apply for variadic functions, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For historical reasons, functions in C can be declared the old way, without a prototype, as:

```
type function()
```

or the new way, with a prototype, as:

```
type function(type parameter)
type function(type parameter, type parameter)
type function(type parameter, type parameter, type parameter)
… and so on
```

Thus, a function declaration in which the types of the parameters are given is said to have a prototype. This affects preparation of the arguments when calling a function. With a prototype, the arguments are converted to the declared types of the parameters. Without a prototype, the arguments are converted to default types, using rules called the *default argument promotions*. (Also, if a function is just being declared, not defined, the names of the parameters can be omitted, leaving a prototype that just lists types, as in `type function(type, type, type)`.)

Because of the old grammar, to declare a function with a prototype that says it has no parameters, you need to explicitly say `void`: `type function(void)`. (This is different in C++, which does not have to support the old grammar. In `C++`, `type function()` is a prototype with no parameters.)

Additionally, a prototype can specify that there are variable arguments by putting `,...` after one or more regular parameters:

```
type function(type parameter,...)
```

In this case, the first arguments are converted to the parameter types, but the arguments that correspond to the `...` are converted using the default argument promotions. `printf` is declared this way.

The default argument promotions are:

- Integers narrower (technically, of lesser rank) than `int` are promoted to `int` if it can represent all the values of the source type or `unsigned int` otherwise.
- `float` arguments are converted to `double`.

There is also some finickiness about bit-fields in the default argument promotions, which I cannot say has ever arisen in code for me.

### History

In the old C grammar, a function would be defined with:

```
type function(name0, name1, name2)
type name0;
type name1;
type name2;
```

and it would be declared without a prototype, as with `type function()`. This means the caller did not know the actual types of the parameters. But you could not just pass a `char` value for a `char` argument or a `short` value for a `short` argument, because C, in trying to be flexible so it could work on many types of computers, had rules about `char` and `short` values being promoted to `int` in expressions. Additionally, character constants like `'X'` have type `int`, not `char`, so, if somebody called a function with `foo('X')`, the compiler would not know if `foo` really wanted just a `char` rather than an `int`. So the default argument promotions were made to match the integer promotions.

Later versions of C fixed this by providing a way to declare the argument types in declarations visible to the caller, so the arguments always match the parameters (and the compiler has more information it can use to provide error messages). But the old grammar still has to be supported so that old code can be compiled.

### More

The phrase in the C standard, “the expression that denotes the called function,” is used because you can call functions through pointers, not just their names. For example, we can write:

```
    int (*FunctionPointer)() = (int (*)()) printf;
```

and then call `printf` using `FunctionPointer("Hello, world.\n");`. Then “the expression that denotes the called function” is `FunctionPointer`, and it does not have a prototype even though `printf` does. (There is no good reason to do this with the `printf` function, but some esoteric code may do some unsavory things.)

You can initially declare a function without a prototype:

```
int foo();
```

and later add a prototype:

```
int foo(float x, char *y);
```

The compiler will merge the declarations, and the resulting `foo` will have a prototype.

Comment: Hello.I had a doubt. When functions are declared with prototypes, can we think as follows: first the usual default promotion takes place, and then this promoted value is truncated or promoted based on the type of the  parameter to which the argument is passed? For example. `int f(char param);` in main `char x=65; f(x);` can we think, x is first promoted to int on the basis of default promotion scheme, and then based on the type of  `param` which is `char` it is again truncated?

Comment: I guess I read this type of explanation in `Herbert Schildt's` C book. Does this thinking approach give different result?

Comment: @AbhishekGhosh: Arguments are not promoted with the default argument promotions and then converted to the parameter types. Per C 2018 6.5.2.2 7, when the expression that denotes the function has a prototype, the arguments corresponding to declared parameters are converted to the parameter types. Trailing arguments corresponding to a `...` after declared parameters are promoted with the default argument promotions. So each argument gets one treatment or the other, not both.

Comment: @AbhishekGhosh: Note that for the arguments being converted to the parameter types, this is a conversion, not a “truncation” or “promotion.” Some conversions may produce results equivalent to removing bits or fractional parts, which may be what you mean by truncation. A promotion is a type of conversion that does not change the value (as when going from an integer type to a wider integer type). All promotions are conversions, but not all conversions are promotions (or truncations).

Comment: @AbhishekGhosh: [Do not use Herbert Schild’s *C: The Complete Reference* to learn C.](https://www.seebs.net/c/c_tcn4e.html)

Comment: This above link, I shall share with my fellow colleagues. :)

Answer (score 0):

The expression that denotes the called function is `printf`, right.

And if you don't provide a prototype for *this function*, for example by not including `<stdio.h>` and not declaring of `printf()` yourself, the compiler recognizes the function as prototype-less.

In your case the first argument is a `const char *`, and the second argument is an `int`.

So, it is *not* `a` that has no prototype, but `printf()`.

The value of `a` will be promoted to `int`.

The assumed prototype will be `int printf();` and takes any number and any type of parameters.

Comment: 1. Including `<stdio.h>` makes later use of `printf()` be regarded as it's prototyped? 2.  You said first argument and second has prototype, (my thought)then printf includes prototype too. But how does '`a` will be promoted...' happen? Is this defined behavior?

Comment: To 1.: Yes, because that header includes a prototype of `printf()`. You can open this file with your editor. -- To 2.: I don't understand the question. A variable can't have a prototype, only functions. BTW, function parameters are a kind of variable. And, yes, the promotion is defined, as your quote shows.

Comment: 1. Writing `<stdio.h>` at the top is same as writing `int printf( const char* str, ...);`, when compiler met `printf("%d", a);`, It goes to `int printf( const char* str, ...);` and printf doesn't include a prototype because of ellipsis `...`, so `a` is promoted to `int`. My comprehension right?? 2. and you mean prototype as "A function prototype is a declaration of a function that declares the types of its parameters." not "Declaration before function's definition" or did you say both meaning of prototype?

Comment: To 1.: Your example with `printf()` is special because of the variadic arguments. Each of these arguments is promoted. What do you mean by "printf doesn't **include** a prototype"? -- To 2.: You got a prototyped function when you declare or define it *before you call it*. You can as well define a function before you call it, and in this case the compiler knows the prototype from the definition. A function prototypes makes the compiler know all datatypes, of all parameters and the returned value.

Comment: Now I understand what's happening, "printf doesn't include a prototype" is my term misuse, but you said "You got a prototyped function when you declare or define it before you call it." It seems function's prototype is same as its firstly declared form regardless of how it is made. Standard's function prototype is specified at 6.2.1 §2.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. (a) Compilers that conform to the modern C standard will not accept functions called without declarations. (b) The distinction of a function with or without a prototype is whether it is declared with a list of parameter types or without, not whether there is a declaration for the function or not.

Comment: *The assumed prototype will be `int printf(const char*, int);`*... you might add that since the inferred prototype is incompatible with the actual definition `int printf(const char*, ...);` the expression `printf("%d", a);` has undefined behavior in the code fragment posted.

Comment: @EricPostpischil "will not accept" has a broad meaning. GCC 9, which I consider to be one of the most modern compilers, accepts to compile it, even though a warning is generated, and the resulting executable runs flawlessly. However, building on this behavior is calling for disaster.

Comment: @thebusybee: I agree, “accept” does not denote the proper concept, and the C standard permits a C implementation to translate an invalid program, although a diagnostic must be issued. So, to be more precise, a program that uses an undeclared function is not a correct program in the sense of C 2018 4 3, and the compiler may not accept it without a diagnostic. The statement “…  the compiler recognizes the function as prototype-less” is not generally true; some compilers may be permissive, but it is incorrect to assure people that this will be so.

Comment: When a compiler does accept an implicit declaration of a function by C 1989 rules, then `printf` will be implicitly declared as `extern int printf();`, not `int printf(const char *, int);`.